# Favicon not showing in Chrome and IE8

Tags: html

Google Chrome and IE8/9 don't display my favicon. Here is my HTML code from the head tag:

```
<link rel="icon" href="images/favi.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favi.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

Can you please solve this issue?

Comment: How have you created the `.ico` file? Are you sure it is a valid icon? Is is indeed in the `images` folder that is relative to the page this is on?

Comment: I'm not sure it's a valid .ico. I just converted in from web. This is the link http://www.convertico.com/

Comment: Then chances are that it isn't. Use proper image editing software to create the `ico` file.

Comment: can you please tell me that software

Comment: My favi.ico file is contain images folder

Comment: Does the browser download your `.ico` file or is it blindly 404ing on `/favicon.ico`? Check your logs to find out. What happens if you use an absolute path (`/images/favi.ico`)?

Comment: Place the icon file in the root with favicon.ico and will work without any reference in html file. Try that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `<link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="path_to_icon/favicon.ico"/>`

Answer (score 1):

put it in the root directory and it should work...
 
`<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">`
 for more info, see here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon
and you should better use the default name **favicon.ico**, 
probably you have to clean your cache in your browser first...